# Perl Concatenating 2 hashes based on a certain key

Tags: perl, hash, concatenation, hashtable

Hi I have two hashes %Asset & %Activity

```
%Asset
Name,Computer Name
David,X
Clark,Y
Sam,Z

%Activity
Name,Activity
David,A
Clark,B
Sam,C
David,D
Clark,E
Sam,F
```

The second hash has the name repeated multiple times (can be more than 2) .. I want to get a hash with the concise infromation.. something like

```
Name,Computer Name,Activity
David,X,A&D
Clark,Y,B&E
Sam,Z,C&F
```

my idea in a pseudo code kind of way is;

```
foreach (@Activity{qw[Name]}) {
    push @Asset{qw[Name Activity]}, $Activity['Activity']

}
```

Comment: Seems to me you want to join two tables and return an array. I don't see any hash involved in your (very confusing) pseudo code.

Comment: Yes, I am open to using Arrays Or Hashes .. the actual goal is to combine them ... the Name would be same in both ...

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a hash of hashes.  Conceptually, you'd combine all information about an asset into a single hash.

```
my %dave = (
    name          => "Dave",
    computer_name => "X",
    activity      => "A"
);
```

Then this goes into a larger hash of all assets keyed by their name.

```
$Assets{$dave{name}} = \%dave;
```

If you want to find Dave's activity...

```
print $Assets{Dave}{activity};
```

You can pull out all information about Dave and pass it around as a hash reference.

```
 my $dave = $Assets{Dave};
 print $dave->{activity};
```

This sort of structure inevitably leads to modelling your assets as objects.

You can learn more about hashes of hashes in the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: The actual problem statement is that I need to combine that information .. how to achieve that efficiently .. The hashes are actually 2 different tables from which I would populate the hash. The field Name is the unique thing between two tables... Second table can have the name repeated more than once, so we need to see all the instances, combine them and then put them in the final hash ..

Comment: @Muzammil I've assumed `%Activity` has the name as the key and the activity as the value like `$Activity{David} = "A"`. There can only be one entry for each name, so no duplicates like you have. But then `@Activity{qw[Name]}` makes no sense. Could you clear this up by editing your post and writing out the data structures you have in actual Perl code?